# Several persons/companies sharing one conference room - Which web app for reservations?

Tags: collaboration, calendar, spreadsheet

My company owns two conference rooms that are sometimes used by other companies as well. At the moment, 15 people can book the room using an Excel sheet on Dropbox.

[image: Screenshot]

One room is green, the other one blue.

It like to use a webapp instead. What I need:

- See one month at a time
- Grant access to people using an email address (invited persons should not have to sign up and other persons should not be able to get access)

I'm totally fine with simple text fields. Also, we don't need any emailing or other messaging options and I'm fine with self hosting.

Any recommendations?

Thanks
Pida